# Where to catch this error?

Tags: exception, node.js, error-handling, express

Im using expressjs

I create the app like this:

```
app.createServer(
  express.cookieParser(),
  express.bodyParser(),
  myfunc1(),
  myfunc2()
);
```

in myfunc1, I return next(err)  for some conditions. (e.g. req.query contains some weird characters).

So, if this happen (  next(err) ), it just simply return http response 500.   I try to catch the error by using:

```
app.error(....)  or
process.on("uncaughtexception" ... );
```

but the error doesnt go to neither of this.  Where does he error go?

Comment: What is the code you were using for `app.error(...);`? I'm pretty sure that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered pretty well in the Express guide:

```
app.use(express.errorHandler({ showStack: true, dumpExceptions: true }));
```

This will capture errors and give you an error screen (for most exceptions).  The guide goes over how to handle 404, 500, etc:

http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling

Happy coding!

Comment: I have done that already. but I set the breakpoint on app.get('/500', ...) and app.error(...) but never reach there.  weird.

Comment: That is odd.  I have an example here of using a custom piece of middleware to do the error handling.  This works for me:  https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/ExpressStarter